# Word VBA: find line and replace font

Tags: vba, replace, fonts, ms-word, format

I've written a VBA Word Macro that read a `.txt` File, copy it and paste it in a Word document setting a new font.

All is working fine! Now I would like to highlight some specific lines with `bold + italic` font, but i cannot figure out a working solution.

The specific lines begins with a specific word (for example `Simulation Nr.xxx`) or they begin with some words but then they have a very long series of blank spaces (for example `Turbine`).

How can i solve the problem?

---

P.s.: here the working code that copy/paste the .txt file into a word document.

```
Sub ACTUS_Table_Converter()

Dim pName As String
Dim bDoc As Document
Dim AppPath, ThisPath As String
Dim Rng As Range

ThisPath = ActiveDocument.Path
pName = ActiveDocument.Name

With Dialogs(wdDialogFileOpen)
    If .Display Then
        If .Name <> "" Then
            Set bDoc = Documents.Open(.Name)
            AppPath = bDoc.Path
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No file selected"
    End If
End With

Call ReplaceAllxSymbolsWithySymbols
Call ChangeFormat

Selection.Copy
Windows(pName).Activate
Selection.Paste
Selection.Collapse
bDoc.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub

Sub ChangeFormat()

Selection.WholeStory
With Selection.Font
    .Name = "Courier New"
    .Size = 6
End With

End Sub

Sub ReplaceAllxSymbolsWithySymbols()

'Call the main "ReplaceAllSymbols" macro (below),
'and tell it which character code  and font to search for, and which to replace with

Call ReplaceAllSymbols(FindChar:=ChrW(-141), FindFont:="(normal text)", _
        ReplaceChar:=ChrW(179), ReplaceFont:="(normal text)")
Call ReplaceAllSymbols(FindChar:=ChrW(-142), FindFont:="(normal text)", _
        ReplaceChar:=ChrW(178), ReplaceFont:="(normal text)")
Call ReplaceAllSymbols(FindChar:=ChrW(-144), FindFont:="(normal text)", _
        ReplaceChar:=ChrW(176), ReplaceFont:="(normal text)")
Call ReplaceAllSymbols(FindChar:="°", FindFont:="(normal text)", _
        ReplaceChar:="", ReplaceFont:="(normal text)")

End Sub

Sub ReplaceAllSymbols(FindChar As String, FindFont As String, _
    ReplaceChar As String, ReplaceFont As String)

Dim FoundFont As String, OriginalRange As Range, strFound As Boolean
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set OriginalRange = Selection.Range
'start at beginning of document
ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select

strFound = False
If ReplaceChar = "" Then
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = FindChar
    .Replacement.Text = ReplaceChar
    .Replacement.Font.Name = "Courier New"
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 6
    .MatchCase = True
End With
If Selection.Find.Execute Then
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=2
    Selection.TypeText ("°C")
End If
Else
With Selection.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = FindChar
    .Replacement.Text = ReplaceChar
    .Replacement.Font.Name = "Courier New"
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 6
    .MatchCase = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With
End If

OriginalRange.Select

Set OriginalRange = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Selection.Collapse

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should run over the document, looking for line starts with `Simulation Nr.` and replace the **whole** line font with bold and italic.

```
Sub ReplaceLinesStartWith()

Dim startingWord As String
'the string to search for
startingWord = "Simulation Nr."

Dim myRange As range
'Will change selection to the document start
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.range(ActiveDocument.range.Start, ActiveDocument.range.Start)
myRange.Select

While Selection.End < ActiveDocument.range.End
   If Left(Selection.Text, Len(startingWord)) = startingWord Then
        With Selection.Font
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = True
        End With
    End If

    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine
    Selection.Expand wdLine

Wend

End Sub
```

Note that I hardcoded the string to search for, you can set it as function argument instead.

Comment: Thanks! that's help me, but don't solve the second case, the one with the random word plus many blank spaces. How can I solve it? I probably have to use some kind of wildcards, but I have no idea how to say search for "unknown word + spaces". do you maybe know it? Thanks in advance. MLC

Comment: You should clearly define what you are searching for. What is consider as 'unknown word'? how many spaces? is there a pattern?

Comment: I have the following problem:
a structured text with some titles in it that i want to highlight with bold font. These Titles are many and i cannot define a find & replace for each one, but i know that if in that line there is a title, than the line will have at least 25 blank spaces after the title word. How can i search and find these lines and change their font to bold?
Thanks