# Word VBA: Replace the space at the end of a line if the preceding character is a digit

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've found this similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680108/word-vba-find-line-and-replace-font), but I don't know how to make it work for what I need.

I need to replace the space (`" "`) at the end of a line if it's preceded by a digit (`"[0-9]"`). Replacement text will be a non-breaking space (`"^s"`). So for example, throughout my document I might have dates written in this format "24 September 2019", phone numbers, phrases like "in 8 days" etc. I need to ensure the line doesn't break between the digit and the following word, hence replacing the space with a non-breaking space.

My code is on a different PC so it's not easy for me to include it, and all I've done so far is copy the one linked above but it doesn't work because I'm not sure which parts I need to amend. So please see the link above for what I've got so far, alternatively any new code that might be more effective is of course welcome.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Don't just do the end of the line.  Replace any number<space> occurrence with a number<non breaking space>.  This is done easily with Words find/replace.

Comment: That's what I currently do and it's not ideal. It results in some unnecessarily long un-broken occurrences, some that I have to then re-break, almost defeating the point.

Answer (score 0):

This should resolve your issue:

```vb
Sub testNBS()

Dim myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Range.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.Start)
myRange.Select
Selection.Expand wdLine

While Selection.End < ActiveDocument.Range.End
    If Right(Selection.Text, 1) = " " And IsNumeric(Left(Selection.Words.Last, 1)) = True Then
        Selection.Characters.Last = Chr(160)
    End If

    Selection.MoveDown wdLine, 1
    Selection.Expand wdLine
Wend
End Sub
```

I changed `Left` to `Right`, added the check for a numeric string, and added in the addition of a non-breaking space (NBS) in place of the last character in the line, which should be a space. I added the `And` clause just to double-check/verify.

Comment: That worked in my quick practice document, but when I come to use it in a letter it only works partially. There are two examples of a line that ends with "25 " then the next line starts with "percent", but neither of these two have the non-breaking space, however in a phone number with the format 0123 456 7890, the non-breaking space goes between the 456 and 7890 as 456 was at the end of the line, but this now leaves 0123 at the end of the line with a regular space after it. I tried repeating the code to get it to run through the doc again but it doesn't do it twice.

Comment: I can't even get the above result anymore. This code results in Word crashing, it appears to be stuck in some sort of loop when the last line of the second last page is highlighted. Removing this code from the macro fixes it again, but I'm not sure what about it makes it break.

Comment: @CatJ I don't understand how it could possibly get stuck in a loop at the second page, assuming that the document is more than two pages. Can you provide more details?