# Replacing a character at the end of the line makes Word crash

Tags: vba, ms-word

I asked [how to replace the space at the end of a line with a non-breaking space if the preceding character is a digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628421/word-vba-replace-the-space-at-the-end-of-a-line-if-the-preceding-character-is-a), throughout the document.

The code below makes my Word crash when it highlights the last line of the second last page of the document.

```
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Range.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.Start)

myRange.Select
Selection.Expand wdLine

While Selection.End < ActiveDocument.Range.End
    If Right(Selection.Text, 1) = " " And IsNumeric(Left(Selection.Words.Last, 1)) = True Then
        Selection.Characters.Last = Chr(160)
    End If

    Selection.MoveDown wdLine, 1
    Selection.Expand wdLine
Wend
```

Comment: We need to know what's on that line in order to have a chance of providing an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have your document in Print Layout view. Changing to Draft view enabled the code to run for me (O365).

Disabling screen updating will help prevent screen flashes and improve performance.

Because lines are of unequal length you also need to collapse the selection before moving it down a line otherwise some lines will get skipped.

```
Sub AddNonBreakingSpace()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'store current view type so it can be restored later
  Dim viewType As WdViewType
  viewType = ActiveWindow.View.Type
  'change to Draft view to prevent crashing
  ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdNormalView

  Dim myRange As Range
  Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Range.Start, ActiveDocument.Range.Start)

  myRange.Select
  Selection.Expand wdLine

  While Selection.End < ActiveDocument.Range.End
    If Right(Selection.Text, 1) = " " And IsNumeric(Left(Selection.Words.Last, 1)) = True Then
      Selection.Characters.Last = Chr(160)
    End If
    'collapse selection to avoid missing any lines
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    Selection.MoveDown wdLine, 1
    Selection.Expand wdLine
  Wend

  'restore original view
  ActiveWindow.View.Type = viewType
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```